# What is the Facebook app ID?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm creating an online quiz website. I have everything setup and I am just working on the social buttons. At the end of the quiz, I want a share button to appear for Facebook and I want to customize the thumbnail and title and stuff like that based on the user's result.

To do this, I am trying to implement the Facebook Javascript SDK, but it needs an app ID. What is this and where do I get it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with Facebook's method for allowing people to use their API, and not about actual programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an facebook app for yourself in [`facebook developer`](https://developers.facebook.com/) site.

After creating it, you can goto YourApp -> Settings

It will have an APP ID

[image]

Comment: I've done that and I got the ID, but now it is giving me an error saying that the domain is not setup. I've already tried adding my domain to the list, but it says the following on Facebook:
"App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: [My Domain Name]"

Comment: You need to add the domain in the settings -> Basic - AppDomains section

Comment: It helped, but I'm still not sure why I can't add my domain. I'll have to ask Facebook.